# silverlight NaN height and width, ActualHeight and ActualWidth also return 0.0 - what is the workaround?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, actualwidth, actualheight

`popUpControl` and `listBoxControl` below are returning `NaN` as the height and width. The `ActualHeight` is also 0.0

Why? and more importantly what is the workaround for this?

```
<Popup Name="popUpControl" IsOpen="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
    <ListBox Name="listBoxControl" SelectionChanged="_ListBox_SelectionChanged"
            Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}" BorderBrush="Transparent"
             MaxHeight="300" MaxWidth="350" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,0,0,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,0,0,0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Popup>
```

Comment: I can see the popup control with the listbox populated. I am checking for the height after I set the listBoxControls itemssource and after opening the popupcontrol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of a FrameworkElement you will have to call `UpdateLayout`.

hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

in WPF and silverlight, a width and/or height of NaN means "Auto"  what you should probably be looking at (and binding to) instead is ActualWidth and/or ActualHeight

Comment: I mentioned in my question that the ActualHeight is also 0.0 - am I misunderstanding something?